# Equivalent tool to Drupal Web Forms

Tags: joomla-3.x

Getting into Joomla and love the system. Wondering if there's an equivalent to Drupal web forms for Joomla or Gravity Forms for Wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

Having used RSForms Pro and Chronoforms, I'd highly recommend Fabrik. Both RSForms Pro and Chronoforms are not really built to be extended, and so will be lacking in comparison to Webform's capability. RSForms Pro will definitely provide much of the our of the box functionality that Webform does, but if you'll be stuck if you want to go beyond that.

Fabrik will let you build the tool you want from the start, and would be straightforward to integrate with CiviCRM.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Gravity Forms or Drupal Web Forms so I'm not too sure of the feature possibilities, but there **are** advanced form builder for Joomla too which you can find on the Forms Category on the Joomla Extensions Directory:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

The ratings and reviews speak for themselves, but remember to test a handful of extensions to see which ones suit your needs the most.

Hope this helps

Comment: Two I'd recommend: RSForms Pro (very powerful, lots of plugins for it and can be made to interact with stuff) and Uniform (drag and drop, multicolumn goodness).

Comment: ChronoForms has been around a long time and is one of the most popular Joomla form builders and interestingly, there is now also a version for WordPress too.

Answer (score 2):

There is sometime since I used gravity forms on a wordpress site, and don't have fresh memories of its features. But there are plenty of powerful forms extensions in Joomla, that will let you build form of any complexity, and even more, like integrating the form with any database table, creating custom apps etc.

Apart of the forms category that Lodder provided, I would also suggest to have a look at the [**CCKs categories**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction) as well.

Extensions like [**Cobalt**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/21340), [**Fabrik**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1659), [**Chrono Connectivity**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/5661) + [**ChronoForms**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508), [**Seblod**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/9128), and more... extend Joomla's potential to many dimensions.